# Smoothwheel only works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, smooth-scrolling

I want to use [this piece of code](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel) to enable smooth scrolling on my website. It works in Chrome but doesn't in Firefox and IE..

You can call Smoothwheel with:

```
$(*container*).smoothWheel();
```

I used 'body' as container, but you can also use a container div. Using a div actually **does** work in Firefox and IE, but I have a lot of scroll events that get screwed up when replacing $(window).scroll with $('#container').scroll..

So my question is **how do I get get $('body').smoothWheel() working in other browsers?**

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meneerfab/xLXj9/18/)

If it isn't possible, then I would like to know how to get scroll events like this working inside a container:

```
currentTop = $(this).scrollTop();
sectionTop = $('#section').scrollTop();
if (currentTop >= sectionTop) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Please don't. That type of scrolling is very annoying. Why do you want to force that sort of behavior on visitors to your site?

Comment: Because parallax effects don't come out great with chunky scrolling. I have a large background image that gets all jittery.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You either have to set:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

on your css, which will work in some browsers but cause layout problems, or:

```
$(document).smoothWheel();
```

which will work on every browser apart from Chrome.

I agree that manipulating scrolling is not ideal, but if you use these settings:

```
fricton = 0.9, // higher value for slower deceleration
vy = 0,
stepAmt = 5,
minMovement = 0.1,
ts = 0.1;
```

it feels very natural.

I'll keep you updated if I figure out a cross-browser way of doing this.

Comment: Update: $(document) works on chrome, I had a cache issue. Just be careful because Macs don't play too well with the settings above.